# Editing dataframe inside loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I seek to implement a loop inside R to retrieve a series of dataframes. Moreover, I want to edit the dataframes inside the loop to tidy the data and set it up as a panel data format.

So, I used assign to be able to assign names inside a loop, such that I got:

```
for(i in 1:2){
    assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), sim_inf10_mun(linha = "Município", coluna = "Ano do Óbito", periodo = c(1996:2016), municipio = "all", 
        capitulo_cid10 = i))
}
```

The "`sim_inf10_mun`" is simply a function that is taking some data online and making a dataframe (it requires library("datasus")). Such as, in this example, I get two dataframes: df1 and df2.

I'd like to conduct the following changes in a dataframe, say, df1,

```
df1 <- df1[-1,]
df1 <- df1[,-ncol(df1)]
df1 <- gather(df1, "ano", "deaths_1", 2:ncol(df1)) 
names(df1)[1]<-"cod_mun"
df1 <- transform(df1, cod_mun = substr(cod_mun, 1, 6))
```

These are simple changes involving variable names, dropping some lines, some columns, etc.

However, I have no idea on how to call df1 inside the loop. I understood how the "assign" function works, at least superficially, but I don't see how I can use it again to make the changes I want to make.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve what I wanted. I'm posting it here in case it may help other people who are finding this difficult.

It was achieved by the simple use of a list.

```
data_list <- list()

for(i in 1:22){
data_list[[i]] <- sim_inf10_mun(linha = "Município", coluna = "Ano do Óbito", periodo = c(1996:2016), municipio = "all", 
                        capitulo_cid10 = i)
data_list[[i]] <- data.frame(data_list[i])
data_list[[i]] <- data_list[[i]][-1,]
data_list[[i]] <- data_list[[i]][,-ncol(data_list[[i]])]
data_list[[i]] <- gather(data_list[[i]], "ano", "deaths_1", 2:ncol(data_list[[i]])) 
names(data_list[[i]])[1]<-"cod_mun"
data_list[[i]] <- transform(data_list[[i]], cod_mun = substr(cod_mun, 1, 6))
}
```